# Why jQuery.after does not work on IE9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/DyRCZ/:

On Chrome:

[image]

On IE9:

[image]

I am using jQuery 1.8.0

Now, I know that IE9 sucks, but IE is one of the 5 major browsers and jQuery is supposed to isolate the developer from the "peculiarities" of IE, isn't it?

So, what is wrong?

Thanks.

**P.S.**

I know the IE subject invites to certain kind of talk, but please - be constructive.

**EDIT**

To all those claiming an array of strings is not working. jQuery 1.8.0 supports it, otherwise it would not have worked neither on Chrome nor on Firefox. But it does on both of them! The only problem is with IE9, which means jQuery 1.8.0 `after()` API is broken there.

**EDIT2**

I think jQuery 1.8.0 has more problems with `after()` even on Chrome. For instance, should the below work?

```
$('#itemsHeader').after("         
                        <tr><td>a</td></tr>");​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/Nw8Hz/

And what about:

```
$('#itemsHeader').after("         <tr><td>a</td></tr>");​
```

The answer is that the former does not work, but the latter works! From the html perspective both are identical and should work. But it does not even on Chrome.

**EDIT3**

I am stupid. Yes I am.

Comment: *Additional Arguments -
Similar to other content-adding methods... .after() also supports passing in multiple arguments as input. Supported input includes DOM elements, jQuery objects, HTML strings, and arrays of DOM elements.* Also from the docs, and the language is a bit clearer. Just because it is working in chrome, does not mean it is an intentional and reliable feature. jQuery standardizes it's *intended* behavior across browsers. Undocumented features can go one way or the other, depending on how the browser's specific js implementation handles a case.

Comment: @nbrooks - I just do not see how passing an array of strings could work accidentally on Firefox and Chrome. Besides, there are other issues with this API on IE9 - see the comments of other people below.

Comment: it could be that those browsers are somehow treating the array as a comma separated value list (supported) instead of a single object...I would love to experiment more with this but sadly I don't have a version of IE to test in. If you figure it out please do update your question and let us know

Comment: p.s. that second edit is not due to invalid html, but invalid javascript - you can't wrap a string into a newline like that, you have to close the string and concatenate it with the new string using a `+`

Comment: lol no worries, happens to the best of us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: On IE9]
http://jsfiddle.net/DyRCZ/3/

I got it working just fine on IE9.  You are passing an array, and not the string of text.  Try joining the array into a string and passing it and you will be fine.

Also, if you want to continue using the array of ELEMENTS, you must create them as such:

http://jsfiddle.net/DyRCZ/10/

```
rows.push($("<tr/>").html('<td colspan="2">This is item ' + i + '</td>'));
```

Comment: Yes, but `jQuery.after()` API supports an array, which is working in Chrome, but not on IE. Which means, jQuery's API is broken on IE.

Comment: Yes, this is weird. http://jsfiddle.net/DyRCZ/6/ Works in Chrome/IE9 with 1.7.2, but fails in IE9 with 1.8.0.

Comment: @pimvd, definitely looks like a bug in the 1.8 API

Comment: Also, I will concur, if it works in one browser, it should technically work in all others...

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery documentation does not state that an array of HTML strings is supported as input.

> > **.after( content [, content] )**
> >
> > **content** HTML string, DOM element, or jQuery object to insert after each element in the set of matched elements.
> >
> > **content** One or more additional DOM elements, arrays of elements, HTML strings, or jQuery objects to insert after each element in the set of matched elements.

**EDIT:** OK, after looking at it again, it can be read in a way that means an array of HTML strings, but I think that is not the way to read it. In this case the documentation is ambiguous and should be fixed.

Comment: What does "arrays of elements, HTML strings, or jQuery objects" mean?

Comment: One or more of the following: 1. DOM elements, 2. arrays of elements, 3. HTML strings, 4. jQuery objects - it's ambigous, I agree, but I'm sure this is the way to read it.

Comment: If "elements, HTML strings, or jQuery objects" would all apply to "arrays" then there should be a word "or" before "arrays". So I guess it means merely "arrays of elements" here.

Comment: Guys! Arrays of strings work on Chrome! It means jQuery 1.8.0 contains the code to deal with it. And this code is broken on IE9. Otherwise, please, explain how an array of strings works on Chrome.

Comment: @mark, agreed.  Its a bug and should be dealt with.  Either they should remove the functionality to strictly deal with arrays of jquery elements, or add the functionality to deal with arrays of strings to the IE9.  pimvdb filed the bug and may get it fixed at the next update.  In the mean time, use a work around. :)

Comment: @mark: Yes, even the syntax that you are supposed to use (multiple arguments) has broken in IE9 as well in 1.8.0. I filed a bug.

Comment: Thanks, guys. For a moment I thought I was crazy.

Comment: I'd say that if it works in Chrome, it might be the side-effect of something. The documentation never said this feature is supported, so strictly speaking, it is not a bug. I'd even say it is **meaningless** to pass in an array of HTML strings when you could have simply concatenated them, use `.join()` on them or build them up in a jQuery object from the beginning...

Comment: @mark It does not work because it is not valid Javascript. You cannot simply put a linebreak in the middle of a string :). It is not related to jQuery at all. Please take a break, calm down :). There is no problem with `.after()` at all. It works as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[The `.after()` API](http://api.jquery.com/after/) supports an array of DOM elements, not explicitly an array of html strings. Just use simple string concatenation:

http://jsfiddle.net/DyRCZ/11/

```
var i, rows = "";

for (i = 0;i < 4; i += 1){
    rows += '<tr><td colspan="2">This is item ' + i + '</td></tr>';
}
$('#itemsHeader').after(rows);​
```

[jQuery docs explaining arguments](http://api.jquery.com/after/#additional-arguments)

*Additional Arguments - Similar to other content-adding methods... .after() also supports passing in multiple arguments as input. Supported input includes DOM elements, jQuery objects, HTML strings, and arrays of DOM elements.*

As is explicitly stated here, an array of strings is not a supported parameter of the method. Just because it is working in chrome, does not mean it is an intentional and reliable feature. jQuery standardizes it's intended behavior across browsers. Undocumented features can go one way or the other, depending on how the browser's specific js implementation handles a case.

Comment: @mark please see my comment on it. you can't attribute every behavior in chrome while jQuery is loaded to some feature that they have added and not decided to share with you